# I want to state color, font, and fontSize in the code. i also want to make each 'showText()' skip a line instead of all on one line

Tags: javascript, console

```
    function Hello(){
        (function () {
            var showText = function(target, msg, index, interval){
                var el = document.getElementById(target);
                if(index < msg.length){
                    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + msg.charAt(index);
                    index = index + 1;
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        showText(target,msg,index,interval);
                        },interval);
                }
            };
            showText("console", "WELCOME ", 0, 50);
            showText("console", "TO ", -8, 50);
            showText("console", "ACE", -5, 200);
        })();
    }
```

Im wanting the text to skip lines each time showText is displayed. but it all goes on a single line. im also wanting to add text color, font, and fontSize. Any ideas?

this is what i was thinking of happening
i want it to be displayed line by line:

> WELCOME
>
> > TO
> >
> > > ACE

```js
        };
        showText("console", "WELCOME ", 0, 50);
        showText("console", "TO ", -8, 50);
        showText("console", "ACE", -5, 200);
    })();
}
```

but instead this happens:

> WELCOME TO ACE

Im thinking of adding color, font, and fontSize but dont know how to add it in. so my pseudo code looks like this:

```js
function Hello() {
  (function() {
    var showText = function(target, msg, index, interval, color, font, fontSize) {
      var el = document.getElementById(target);
      if (index < msg.length) {
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + msg.charAt(index);
        index = index + 1;
        //--------------------------------------------------
        //Make 'color' go here!!!
        //----------------------------------------------------
        //Make 'font' go here!!!
        //------------------------------------------------------
        //Make 'fontSize' go here!!!
        //------------------------------------------------------
        setTimeout(function() {
          showText(target, msg, index, interval, color, font, fontSize);
        }, interval);
      }
    };
    showText("console", "WELCOME ", 0, 50);
    showText("console", "TO ", -8, 50);
    showText("console", "ACE", -5, 200);
  })();
}
Hello();
```